# After I installed php 7.x phpinfo is still showing older php 5.x

Tags: apache-2.2, php

After I installed php 7.x phpinfo is still showing older php 5.x

should i purge the older version? or what?

thanks

Comment: **How** did you install PHP7?

Comment: follwing all the similar guides around the web like http://markhodder.com/upgrading-php-5-x-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-apache/

Comment: Have you restarted apache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found out that a module was enabled and causing conflict

so i deleted the `php5filter.load`

Comment: You deleted this module causing the wrong view of the version number and solved the problem with that, then? If so, please you should mark your answer as solved, no?

Answer (score 4):

If you have this problem while upgrading from PHP5 to PHP7 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache, here's what helped me (credit goes [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-v-is-7-0-11-and-phpinfo-is-5-5-9)):

Disable PHP5 module on Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
```

Now enable PHP7:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

To reflect changes Apache restart is required:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: or if you are on php 7.0 you do `sudo a2enmod php7.0`